# Cannot resolve LAN hostname when connected using Wireguard

Tags: networking, dns, hostname, wireguard, mdns

My LAN has a Wireguard server than my laptop connects to from a remote location.

```
                                         |                |
                                         |                |
Laptop -> Router (WG client) -> Router -----> (INTERNET) -----> Router -> WG server 
                                         |                |          ∟--> foo
                                         |                |
```

However, when using the Wireguard tunnel, the laptop is unable to ping/ssh to a machine using its hostname `foo`, and is only able to reach it using its IP address `192.168.1.101`

```
% ping foo
ping: cannot resolve foo: Unknown host

% nslookup host foo           
nslookup: couldn't get address for 'foo': not found

% ping 192.168.1.101
PING 192.168.1.101 (192.168.1.101): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.1.101: icmp_seq=0 ttl=63 time=27.082 ms
```

There is no problem accessing `foo` using its hostname from another machine on the network.

```
$ ping foo
PING foo.localdomain (192.168.1.101) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from foo.localdomain (192.168.1.101): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.094 ms


$ nslookup foo
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   foo.localdomain
Address: 192.168.1.101


$ nslookup foo 192.168.1.1
Server:     192.168.1.1
Address:    192.168.1.1#53

Name:   foo.localdomain
Address: 192.168.1.101
```

The Wireguard profile used by my laptop contains the lines under `[Interface]`:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.116.51.3/24
DNS = 192.168.1.1, 9.9.9.9, 149.112.112.112
```

Is there any way to allow the laptop using Wireguard tunnel to reach the LAN machines via their hostnames? The LAN is running on a Unifi Dream Machine and some Unifi switches.

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: @user68186 Ubuntu 22.04 on the Wireguard server and on `foo`. Mac OS X 12.6 on the laptop.

Comment: Someone else [asked a similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1434901/how-to-use-wireguard-lan-only) the other day. I don't have any solution.